# How to implement event notification mechanism in AIR

Tags: actionscript-3, air, event-handling

Do you know how to implement event notification mechanism in AIR ? For simplicity, consider an example:

I want to build two applications: "television" and "remote". Among them, television is implemented using AIR. For the "television" I want to use my *remote* to send message to the *television*.

How must I do to implement "television" in such way that, it runs in waiting mode and whenever it receives a message from "remote", it will process the message and make a suitable action (i.e. change channel, increase volume...).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you considered having only one application but with two separate windows in it?

Comment: No, Infact, "television" is a stand-alone application. It runs in standby mode, and waiting for incoming message. For i.e you send me a message via your cell phone, whenever my application,  who acts as my cell phone, receives ur message, it will display it (here, "suitable action" means display message)

Comment: Check out Cirrus. http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/cirrus/

Comment: Two apps on the same machine? Try LocalConnection then.

Comment: It's rather in network, can I use web service instead ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the remote is not a Flash technology based application, use UDP message exchanges, webservices would require endless polling.